# Storing meta about a cropped photo

Tags: mysql, storage

Want to know how to save cropped images in the database? The info about the images or reference to the cropped images in itself?

Working on a marketplace for artists where artists can upload their work. The way the app is designed, most artists asked us to provide them with a functionality to **crop their images so they look good on their profiles**

I propose two solutions and wanted to know if they are feasible:

1. When a user has cropped the photo, save that cropped photo in your storage and store the cropped photo's path in the table
2. I was exploring the internet and I found a library which allows the user to crop the image and when he/she's done, the library returns a meta object about the image, it's co-ordinates, width height etc.

I'd like to know your thoughts, the first one consumes memory, the second one causes rendering issue since I'll have to show the image based on the co-ordinates

Comment: What kind of rendering issue will you have with the second option?

Comment: Are you referring to profile pictures? If so, externalize that and link them out to gravatar. That's what everyone uses.

Comment: @pconcepcion I'll show you a code example to help better understand:

Let's say we have a 1080x960 image and given the co-ordinates (let's say 600x480) I'll have to do <img width='600' height ='480' /> which means it will load the original big-size photo when the page loads although I'll be rendering it differently given the co-ordinates.

Comment: @EvanCarroll Ah nope, showing the featured image of a project the artist uploads. On the profile page of the artist, I show featured images of his/her projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's order things by complexity and performance.

1. The cropped image will be displayed many times.  And cropping is a rather complex process.  So, store the *cropped* image *as a file*.  Note:  By storing as a file, you can simply use an `<img src=...>` tag in HTML to fetch it -- no extra processing (for you) when providing the web page.
2. Given that you are doing #1, the rest becomes somewhat moot.  Yes, you could store the original image somewhere, plus meta info about cropping.  But will you ever change the cropping?  Or maybe the only real use case is when the user resends the image and you redo the cropping?  My point is, you business model now takes over and answers what to do for #2; not database considerations.

Answer (score 0):

You **should keep the original** in case you want to do a different croping or show the original at some time. In that case I can think on 3 options.

### Keep a copy of the cropped image and save the reference

This is your first solution, it's simple and works, but **it will take some extra space** for the images and it's limited in the sense that you will have to add a new column for each crop of the image or have a secondary table with the cropping references. So it's not that flexible.

### Just keep the crooping information on the database

You can **keep just the information about the cropping** coordinates (sounds like your second solution) on the datbase and serve dynamically the cropped image on demand. This will save some space as you will not need to store the images and with the apropiate **caching** can be quite effective. In this case you may not need to add any extra columns or tables, because as the cropping is dynamic can be part of the img link.

### Use an external image server

You can also **use an image server** like [Picfit](https://medium.com/@thoas/introduction-to-picfit-an-image-resizing-server-written-in-go-c8320c017d41) or [Imaginary](https://github.com/h2non/imaginary) that will take care of the image handling for you and you will just have to **save the reference to the file** on the image server and will be able to **serve it dinamically using different URL parameters**.